# Geometric progression in an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

**Problem: Show that if $a>0$ and $n>3$ is an integer then $$\frac{1+a+a^2 \cdots +a^n}{a^2+a^3+ \cdots a^{n-2}} \geq \frac{n+1}{n-3}$$**

---

I am unable to prove the above the inequality.

I used the geometric progression summation formula to reduce it to proving $\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a^2(a^{n-3}-1)} \geq \frac{n+1}{n-3}$.

Also writing it as $$\frac{1+a+a^2 \cdots +a^n}{n+1} \geq \frac{a^2+a^3+ \cdots a^{n-2}}{n-3}$$
 seems to suggest that some results on mean-inequalities can be used but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Have you tried using induction on n? Also $\frac{1+\cdots +a^n}{a^2+\cdots +a^{n-2}}=\frac{1+a+a^{n-1}+a^n}{a^2+\cdots +a^{n-2}}+1$.

Comment: @MoseWintner i tried using that identity but it didnt help me. And I am unable to see to how to use induction without cross multplying (aftr taking two cases a>1 and a<1 ). But after cross mutlplying the expression is becoming somewhat complicated.

Comment: Try combining Mose Wintners comment with $n+1 = (n-3)+4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, that identity is useful. In details, by AM-GM inequality, $$ \left(n-3\right)\left(1+a^n\right) \ge 2\left(a^2+\cdots+a^{n-2}\right) $$ and $$ \left(n-3\right)\left(a+a^{n-1}\right) \ge 2\left(a^2+\cdots+a^{n-2}\right) $$ Thus, $$ LHS = \frac{1+a+a^{n-1}+a^{n}}{a^2+\cdots+a^{n-2}}+1 \ge \frac{4}{n-3}+1 =RHS $$

Comment: The arithmetic mean of the first and last term of a geometric progression is greater than the arithmetic mean of all terms in between. Why ?

Comment: It suffices to prove $ 1+a^k \ge a+a^{k-1} $. Then using AM-GM, we have $$ \left(k-1\right)\cdot 1+a^k \ge ka $$ Also, $$ 1+\left(k-1\right)\cdot a^k \ge ka^{k-1} $$ Add this two inequalities, we get the result.

Comment: Another way to see this.  By the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality),
we have for $m \ge 1$,
$$
1 + a^n = 1\times 1 + a^m\times a^{n-m} \ge 1\times a^m + a^{n-m} \times 1 = a^m + a^{n-m}.
$$
Summing the above result from $m = 2$ to $n-2$, yields
$$
(n-3) (1 + a^n) \ge 2 \, (a^2+\cdots a^{n-2}).
$$
We can similarly show
$$
(n-3) (a + a^{n-1}) \ge 2 \, (a^2+\cdots a^{n-2}).
$$

Answer (score 0):

What you may also consider, but this is more clunky than other suggestions, is to write $\lambda(n,a) = 1 + a + ... + a^n$ and $\mu(n,a) = a^2 + a^3 + ... + a^{n-2}$ and notice that $\lambda(n,a=1) = n + 1$, $\mu(n,a=1) = n - 3$, so that the equality holds for $a = 1$. Then you would have to show that the function $g(n,a) = \frac{\lambda(n,a)}{\mu(n,a)}$ has a maximum at $a = 1$, so would need to calculate $\frac{d g(n,a)}{d a}$ and $\frac{d^2 g(n,a)}{d^2 a}$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality holds trivially for $a = 1$, and it is invariant
under the substitution $a \to 1/a$. Therefore it suffices to
prove the inequality for $\mathbf{a > 1}$.

The hyperbolic sine is a *convex* function on $[0, \infty)$,
so for $a > 1$ the function 
$$
   f(x) = 2 \sinh \bigl(\log a \cdot \frac x2 \bigr) 
= a^{x/2} - a^{-x/2}
= \frac{a^x - 1}{a^{x/2}} \quad (x \ge 0)
$$
is also convex, and therefore
$$
 \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{a^x - 1}{x \, a^{x/2}}
$$
is *increasing*. It follows that for $0 \le x \le y$
$$
   \frac{a^y - 1}{y \, a^{y/2}} \ge \frac{a^x - 1}{x \, a^{x/2}} 
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
  \frac{a^y-1}{a^x-1} \ge a^{(y-x)/2} \frac yx \, .
$$

The desired inequality follows as a special case for $x = n-3$
and $y = n+1$, but we have shown that the inequality can be
generalized to arbitrary positive real numbers as exponents.